# Hiding an application from switcher (alt+tab)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, cairo-dock

I would like to hide cairo-dock from the switcher since it is redundant to have it there.

I've searched for solutions without any luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it after finding a small thread on Ubuntu forums. I think this solution can be applied to any program

Install compizconfig-settings-manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Go into `Window Managment` and `Window Rules`, there add:

```
Skip taskbar: title=Cairo-Dock
Skip pager: title=Cairo-Dock
```

and finally go back to the main settings and enable the `Window Rules` by checking the box

---

It is also possible to change the switcher by activating the ring or shift switcher and replacing the Unity shortcut with the custom switcher. In their respective menus you can choose what kind of windows it should display.

Comment: While this answer may be valid, you can also willingly exlude your own app from the task switcher from within the app itself.  It's my opinion that this would make sense for some applications... like cairo-dock or the xfce app dock.

Comment: @hbdgaf From within cairo-dock? How?

Comment: Anyone knows this for Ubuntu 16.04? I can't find the `Window Rules` in the CompizConfig Settings Manager in 16.04