# How to hide an application from window switcher (alt-tab) in 14.04

Tags: unity, application-switcher

How can I hide an application from the <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> menu for Unity?

An [older post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437090/hiding-an-application-from-switcher-alttab) suggested using compizconfig-settings-manager.

> Install compizconfig-settings-manager:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
> ```
>
> Go into **Window Managment** and **Window Rules**, there add:
>
> ```
> Skip taskbar: title=Cairo-Dock
> Skip pager: title=Cairo-Dock
> ```
>
> and finally go back to the main settings and enable the *Window Rules* by checking the box

However, in compizconfig-settings-manager for 14.04, there is no *Window Rules* option.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to install the extra plugin.

1. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal
2. type `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra`
3. press <kbd>Y</kbd> a couple of times

*Window Rules* should be there now.

Answer (score 0):

This command temporarily hides the currently active window from most window switchers:

`xdotool getactivewindow windowstate --toggle SKIP_PAGER`